# Sum of sub-gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation, gaussian

1 - If X is $\sigma_1$-subgaussian and Y is $\sigma_2$-subgaussian (not necessarily independent), then is it true that X+Y is $(\sigma_1 + \sigma_2)$-subgaussian?

I got $\sqrt{2 \sigma_1^2 + 2 \sigma_2^2}$-subgaussian by applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on moment generating function, but I couldn't figure out something anymore.

---

2 - For any random variable X and Y, can we say $Y-E[Y|X]$ is independent of X?

I heard that $E[Y|X]$ is a kind of 'projection' of Y onto X, so can we say $Y-E[Y|X]$ is independent of X because $Y-E[Y|X]$ is 'orthogonal' to X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is correct but can be tightened using Holder's inequality instead of Cauchy Schwarz:

$$\mathbb{E}e^{t(X+Y)} \leq (\mathbb{E}e^{tXp})^{1/p}(\mathbb{E}e^{tY(1-p)})^{1/(1-p)}$$

Then applying the known subgaussianity and optimizing $p$ to minimize this upper bound we get $p = \sigma_2/\sigma_1 +1$ giving that $X+Y$ is $\sigma_1 + \sigma_2$ sub-gaussian.

$E(Y- E[Y|X])g(X) =0$ for all measurable $g$ by definition, so they are uncorrelated but not necessarily independent.

Comment: 1. You mean $\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}$? or $\sqrt{2} (\sigma_1 + \sigma_2)$? How could you prove that tight boud?

Comment: What I did : $E[\exp(\lambda (X+Y))] \leq \sqrt{E[\exp(2\lambda X)]E[ \exp(2\lambda Y)]} \leq \sqrt{\exp(2\lambda^2 (\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2))}=\exp(\lambda^2 (\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2))$. $\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}$ only holds for independent X and Y as long as I know.......

Comment: I had originally missed that they might be dependent, I updated with a slightly tighter bound.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for your brilliant idea. I completely forgot about Holder inequality.